# How do I handle mid-term paypal subscription upgrades/downgrades using php?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I am developing a website that has monthly and annual plans. For argument's sake

Basic Monthly

- 30 day free trial
- rebills $5/month thereafter

Basic Yearly

- 30 day free trial
- rebills $50/year thereafter

If a user signed up for Basic Monthly and started paying me (i.e. is in his second month) and wants to upgrade to Basic Yearly then how do I set that up?Does Paypal API provides any mechanism for switching the customer's plan and automatically calculating the details like pro-rating as does Stripe?